# searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch goes out of the UIView when end searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uisearchbar

I've a `UIView` in which I've placed a `UISearchBar` and a `UIButton` below are the screenshots that explains the problem:
[image: This is how it appears when I first run the app]
^This is how it appears when I first run the app
[image: This is how it gets when I want to enter the text]
^This is how it gets when I want to enter the text
[image: Finally this is the size it gets after I end the search]
^Finally this is the size it gets after I end the search
The most important point here is that I'm not using `UINavigationBar` the red is a `UIView`. I've haven't coded anything for it's UI, I just placed it in the `.xib` and set it via `autoResizing`. They only this I wrote for `UISearchBar` was `[_searchBarTop setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];` which was just to get the background image vanished.
**I've tried** `self.searchBarTop.clipsToBounds = YES;` and this

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    {
        self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    }
```

**I'm using searchdisplaycontroller and want to use that**
But it's still the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a simple `UISearchBar` in a `UIView`, you don't need to use `UISearchController` per sè. You can simply use `UISearchBar` and it's respective delegates instead.

As for the resizing issue, I think you have the autoresizing at flexible width, whereas you need static width, with static sides. Apply this to both your UIView and the embedded `UISearchBar`. That should fix your issue. Let me know if the problem persists.

If autoresizing doesn't work, you can just force it back like this:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGRect frame = self.searchBarTop.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 33;
    frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 41;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.searchBarTop.frame = frame;
    }];
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UISearchDisplayController was first deprecated in iOS 8.0, as indeed was UISearchDisplayDelegate. You should use UISearchController its delegate, UISearchControllerDelegate and its searchBar property instead.

**EDIT** - Add Example

```
 // your class needs to conform to the following protocols 

 <UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate>
 // define property for your search controller
 @property (nonatomic) UISearchController *mySearchController;

 // instantiate the search controller - in viewDidLoad should work
 // if you want to handle results manually the searchResultsController can be nil, or you can set it to

 self.mySearchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
 [self.mySearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
 self.mySearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
 self.mySearchController.delegate = self;
 self.mySearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

 // add the searcher to a properly constrained "Container" or "wrapper" UIView 
 [self.containerView addSubView:self.mySearchController.searchBar];
 [self.mySearchController.searchBar sizeToFit]; 
 self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

you can then respond to the input in the search bar by implementing the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol's required method:

```
 - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
      NSString *text = searchController.searchBar.text;
      /// do whatever you need to with the text typed in to the search bar
 }
```

And Finally, always read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/)

Comment: can you share an example?